# is index same for same elements?

Tags: python, list, indexing

```
nums = [11, 2,4, 2, 5]
for i in nums:
    print(nums.index(i),i )
```

I run the above code and it uses same index for similar elements(here 2 at index 1 and 3).
I wasn't aware of this python list behavior, does it mean the use of lists can be restrictive for similar elements in same list?

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) for the method? The `index` method returns *the first item whose value is equal to* the argument.

Comment: it sure does, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `index()` method returns the position at the first occurrence of the specified value.
So it returns first index of number 2.

```
nums = [11, 2,4, 2, 5]
```

You can `enumerate()` to get all indexes.

```
nums = [11, 2,4, 2, 5]
for i,n in enumerate(nums):
    print(i, n)


0 11
1 2
2 4
3 2
4 5
```